# Is Sanskrit literature really oldest?

Tags: puranas, history, evidence

Is Sanskrit literature oldest ?
The history is showing proofs that Sanskrit literature is only in 1st century
But Hebrew literature is 10th century B.C.E

But we are saying that our puranas are written in 5000 B.C.E. years ago

Then any inscriptions are there in Sanskrit which is oldest 5000 B.C.E

Comment: FYI, yes/no questions in English begin with "Is", not "Do".

Comment: If you want from Historical aspect, then this question is off-topic since it does not belong to Hinduism. If your question is from scriptural aspect then YES, Sanskrit is older one.